# Euler's conjecture about ${a_1}^n+{a_2}^n+\cdots+{a_{n-1}}^n=b^n$

Tags: number-theory

I've known the followings:

**Euler's conjecture** : There is no non-trivial integer solution $(a_1, \cdots, a_n, b)$ such that 
$${a_1}^n+{a_2}^n+\cdots+{a_{n-1}}^n=b^n$$
for $n\ge 3.$

It is known that some counterexamples have been found.

For the $n=5$ case, 
$$27^5+84^5+110^5+133^5=144^5.$$

For the $n=4$ case,
$$95800^4+217519^4+414560^4=422481^4.$$

However, I don't know anything about the $n\ge 6$ case. Then, here is my question.

**Question** : Do you know anything about the $n\ge 6$ case? If you have any helpful information, please let me know it.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_sum_of_powers_conjecture) no counter-example for $n>5$ is known.

Comment: @Maesumi: I've known it. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: There are some identities, but no answer at the following https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/Home

Comment: @MarkBennet: Thank you very much.